# Is it necessary to get a new GCM registration when device is updated?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Is it true that when a device is updated, it is necessary, or a good idea, to get a new registration ID from GCM?

Comment: I dont know what you need to when the device updates but when you update your app you should yes because it is not guaranteed to work after an app update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google recommend to get a new registration ID when the app is updated (or at least to register again to GCM, which may or may not result in a new registration ID). Is that what you mean?

If, on the other hand, you mean an update of a device's Android version, I've seen no mention of that in the GCM docs.

Comment: I have seen discussions about when the android version is updated, the registration ID should be updated; I just wanted to know if there is any truth to that.

Comment: @user3935018 Do you have any links to such discussions? I haven't seen anything official on the matter.

Comment: Here is a link: https://blog.pushbullet.com/2014/02/12/keeping-google-cloud-messaging-for-android-working-reliably-techincal-post/

Comment: @user3935018 It was an interesting read, but I can't confirm it. I found a registration ID that was created for my app when my device was running Android 2.2. Now my device is running 2.3.6 (I know, it's old, I need to get a new device) and this old registration ID still works (even though it returns a canonical registration ID, since I got several newer registration IDs for my device since then). I'm yet to see a case in which you get a new registration ID from GCM and the old one stops working.

Comment: Thank you for the information; Have you ever seen the second lesson happen from the link?